# How do I load, render and transform 2D images using Direct3D 11 API?

Tags: c++, directx, 2d, direct3d, direct3d11

In my small game project using DirectX 11 API, I create Direct3D device, and drawing 3D meshes, using tutorials on web and a book. But I cannot found how to **load**, **transform** (rotate, scale, resize) and **draw** 2D sprites (loaded from PNG files, for example).

Is there any tutorials, articles or books about using 2D graphics with Direct3D API?

UPDATE: **transform** and **render** images *without* third-party libraries.

Comment: Have you looked at the DirectXTK [SpriteBatch](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SpriteBatch) library?  It's not technically part of D3D proper but it's from MS and is distributed as source, so you can use it directly or just copy the parts you need.

Comment: ``SpriteBatch`` is all open source, so you can use it as a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DirectX Tool Kit's `SpriteBatch` is ideal for exactly what you are describing, and is hosted on both [CodePlex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) and [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK).

Start with the [Sprites and textures](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sprites%20and%20textures&referringTitle=Getting%20Started) tutorial.

DirectX Tool Kit is all open source C++, so you can use it as a tutorial if you don't want to use it directly in your app for some reason--it's a static library with no runtime dependencies beyond Direct3D 11 itself. Just step right into the code.